# spring boot version update: test not running (maven surefire)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I updated spring version from 2.3.4.RELEASE to 2.4.4 and all of my tests are not running. I found the solution to make it work, but I am not sure why.

I got this from other people's spring version update. However, I am not sure what this plug in (specially configuration) means and why tests were not running when updated to 2.4.4 and why it is running when I added this plug-in..

I am pretty new to spring and maven, so any answer would help me.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.4 switch to Junit5 and thus excluded, most of, the junit4 stuff. If you want to run your Junit4 tests with JUnit5 you will need some additional dependencies (and then you don't need to modify the surefire plugin). Or move your tests to JUnit5 instead of JUnit4. This is even mentioned in the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#junit-5s-vintage-engine-removed-from-spring-boot-starter-test). So for the next upgrade, please read the upgrade guide instead of blindly upgrading dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was upgrade guide. I appreciate for providing me the link and I will make sure to read it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this dependency, pointing to an specific version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
        <version>{version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

It worked after removing the version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```